# Не выполняется событие в js

Tags: javascript, html, css

При клике на кнопку "следующий вопрос" должен изменится вопрос, но почему-то он не меняется.

```js
var FQCorrectAnswer = 45,
  Counter = 0,
  FirstAns = document.getElementById('fa'),
  SecondAns = document.getElementById('sa'),
  ThirdAns = document.getElementById('ta');

function checkFirstQuestion(n) {
  FirstAns.style.backgroundColor = "#C85858";
  SecondAns.style.backgroundColor = "#C85858";
  ThirdAns.style.backgroundColor = "#5BC660";
  if (n == FQCorrectAnswer) {
    Counter++;
  }
  FirstAns.disabled = true;
  SecondAns.disabled = true;
  ThirdAns.disabled = true;
}

function QuestionReady() {
  if (document.getElementById('second').style.display == "block") {
    document.getElementById('second').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('third').style.display = "block";
  }
  if (document.getElementById('first').style.display == "block") {
    document.getElementById('first').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('second').style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/*Обнуление*/

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:focus,
 :active {
  outline: none;
}

a:focus,
a:active {
  outline: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

a,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #4D3B80;
  color: #fff;
}

.header {
  max-width: 720px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 96px;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  line-height: 94px;
}

.question__title {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 65px;
}

.answers {
  margin-top: 105px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.btn {
  padding: 16px 84px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(55, 41, 95, 0.75);
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin-left: 57px;
}

.btn:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(135, 117, 188, 0.75);
}

.btn:focus {
  background-color: rgba(135, 117, 188, 0.75);
}

.confirm-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.confirm {
  margin-top: 115px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(116, 2, 186, 0.92);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 30px 109px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px #6400A1;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.confirm:hover {
  margin-top: 117px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px #6400A1;
}

#result {
  display: none;
}

#first {
  display: block;
}

#second,
#third,
#fourth,
#fifth,
#sixth,
#seventh,
#eighth,
#ninth,
#tenth {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,900&display=swap&subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="scss/style.css">
  <title>IQ Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <h1 class="title">IQ Test</h1>
    <div class="questions" id="first">
      <p class="question__title">1. Каким числом следует заменить знак вопроса? 25 29 33 37 41 ?</p>
      <div class="answers">
        <button class="btn" onClick="checkFirstQuestion('43')" id="fa">43</button>
        <button class="btn" onClick="checkFirstQuestion('44')" id="sa">44</button>
        <button class="btn" onClick="checkFirstQuestion('45')" id="ta">45</button>
      </div>
      <div class="confirm-center"><button class="confirm" onClick="QuestionReady();">Следующий вопрос</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="questions" id="second">
      <p class="question__title">2. Найдите слово, которое необходимо вставить в скобки, чтобы закончить первое слово и начать последнее слово. Какую букву содержит это слово? БАЛ ( . . . ) ТУР</p>
      <div class="answers">
        <button class="btn" onClick="checkFirstQuestion('43')" id="fa">А</button>
        <button class="btn" onClick="checkFirstQuestion('44')" id="sa">Н</button>
        <button class="btn" onClick="checkFirstQuestion('45')" id="ta">С</button>
      </div>
      <div class="confirm-center"><button class="confirm" id="next" onclick="QuestionReady()">Следующий вопрос</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="questions" id="third">
      <p class="question__title">3. Какой буквой следует заменить знак вопроса? Б Г Е Ж И ?</p>
      <div class="answers">
        <button class="btn" onClick="checkFirstQuestion('43')" id="fa">К</button>
        <button class="btn" onClick="checkFirstQuestion('44')" id="sa">М</button>
        <button class="btn" onClick="checkFirstQuestion('45')" id="ta">Л</button>
      </div>
      <div class="confirm-center"><button class="confirm" id="result" onclick="Question">Проверить</button></div>
    </div>
  </header>



  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function QuestionReady() {
  if (window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('second')).display == "block") {
    document.getElementById('second').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('third').style.display = "block";
  }
  if (window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('first')).display == "block") {
    document.getElementById('first').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('second').style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, если не сложно можете сказать в чем различие window и document и что делает getComputedStyle?

Comment: @Chim `window` - объект, содержащий все "глобальные" переменные и функции, в том числе и `document`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle. Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.